# Should nginx questions be on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

In my opinion nginx configuration must be all moved to Server Fault. There was also an idea to make nginx-config tag and move the questions to Server Fault or somehow signal posters that the question is off topic but then again nginx-related questions are almost all about "how do I configure nginx to ... " . All in all, nginx is just another HTTP server, much like apache. What will community say?

Comment: it's a fine line. we're allowing apache and node questions do we not? some of those cover very similar topics to the nginx config

Comment: To move *all* is definitely not something we want to be doing -- Server Fault already has their own quality issues.

Comment: @Jorg apache configuration is off-topic as well, isn't it?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy so let's pollute Stack Overflow instead?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: well if it's not on topic for either, close and delete these questions! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites

Comment: Here's me admitting I don't know nginx real well but I was under the impression the conf was used in, amongst others, a similar way to htaccess which is very much on topic. Same with node server set up. It's tied in very closely to making a webapp work.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Your link doesn't apply - it talks about low-quality questions. Of course I vote to close such questions as they belong to Server Fault IMHO but if there's some way to make this more automated (or at least a hint to be given to posters), why not use it.

Comment: I think this should be resolved, as just a typical user I don't know which one I should post my nginx questions to...

Comment: See: [Apache configuration/.htaccess questions (esp. mod\_rewrite): SO or SF?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283038/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-mod-rewrite-so-or-sf)