# Apache configuration/.htaccess questions (esp. mod_rewrite): SO or SF?

Tags: discussion

The title says it all, in not so many words... there are a lot of questions on StackOverflow about Apache configuration, especially on the proper way to create `RewriteRule`s for some particular URL mapping.  I personally think that these kinds of questions would be more appropriate for ServerFault, as Apache configuration is a sysadmin-type activity, not really a programming thing. (I know `mod_rewrite` is powerful but it's not quite a full-blown programming language ;-)

So what does the community think? Do Apache configuration questions belong on SF or SO?

*EDIT*: examples aplenty:

- [How to remove part of a URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139349/how-to-remove-part-of-a-url-using-htaccess)
- [Mod_Rewrite: Insert "/" between variables and values in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134535/modrewrite-insert-between-variables-and-values-in-url)
- [How can I append HTTP_REFERER to query string using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132268/how-can-i-append-httpreferer-to-query-string-using-htaccess)

and many others like that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My gut says "belongs on SF", since it's a matter of web server configuration. On the other hand, the rewrite engine is often used for programming purposes in developing web apps; if it can show up in the app requirements, it's at least somewhat programming related.

Add "[Mod Rewrite complete befuzzlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807410/mod-rewrite-complete-befuzzlement/1807442)" to the list of rewrite questions on SO, mostly because the question comments includes a mini-discussion about this very topic:

> Now that I've already given an answer for this, it really belongs on ServerFault. – outis Nov 27 at 8:50
>
> This is a kind of programming so it's OK on stackoverflow. – Kinopiko Nov 27 at 8:56
>
> But it's not programming--it's a configuration issue. There's nothing wrong with the RE. Most importantly, the average SF user is going to be more knowledgeable about this than the average SO user; Antony's more likely to get better help on SF. – outis Nov 27 at 10:06
>
> Maybe, but Serverfault is fairly low-traffic. – Kinopiko Nov 27 at 13:21

Comment: I resent that someone things SF is Low Traffic. Most (read: good) questions don't go un-answered for more than 10 minutes.

Comment: And even if SF is low traffic (while Kinopiko asserted it, I don't know how true it is), not using it isn't the solution, using it is.

Comment: gray area, as I said in my answer here. Use what's in your job title as the deciding factor. Is it "programmer"? Or something else?

Comment: Is this still the right advice?  In my experience the vast majority of Apache configuration questions are too basic for the typical SF user (and certainly not indicative of coming from a "professional" system administrator), so I tend to mark them better for superuser.com instead.

Comment: @Alnitak `.htaccess`-only questions are almost off-topic on SF, since on SF it is assumed you have access to the main server-config (which mostly renders `.htaccess` redundant). `.htaccess` questions often get closed as a duplicate of a _catch-all_ question, whether it answers the question or not. If you feel the need to mark the Q for migration, consider migrating to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com - where it is probably on-topic. `.htaccess` files are generally _application_ config files that every webmaster must deal with at some point.

Answer (score 17):

A truly gray area. Pick whichever site you think suits your question better, and go with it.

I'd also suggest that if your job title contains the word "programmer", go with Stack Overflow, and if your job title does *not*, then go with Server Fault.

Answer (score 9):

If they concern a production environment which is hosted on your (or your company's servers) then they should probably be asked on Server Fault.

If they concern a production environment which is hosted by someone else then they should probably be asked on Webmasters.

If they concern a development environment (i.e on your development machine for testing) then they should probably be asked on Stack Overflow.

Though it is an area that straddles both development (rather than just programming) and system administration.

Comment: Hey @ChrisF, you should have just gotten an email from me inviting you to a pre-screening session hosted by Stack Exchange. We've got dates this upcoming Monday and Tuesday, so if you are interested, could you let me know what times might work best for you?

Answer (score 8):

I would think that question which overlap the system could be asked in either of their overlapping sites.